# How do you find the Open Sets of a Topology

Tags: general-topology

Define $\mathbb{S}=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with topology $\mathbf{T_{\mathbb{S}}}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\mathbb{S}\}$. How would you go about finding the closed and open sets? Are the open sets just the elements of the topology? Thank you sorry for the very basic question.

I was trying to think about this using the definition of limit points: Let $(X,\mathbf{T})$ be a topological space, and $S$ is a subset of $X$, a point $p$ in $X$ is a $\mathbf{T}$-limit point of $S$ if every element of $\mathbf{T}$ containing $p$ meets $S$ in a point other than $p$.

Comment: What's the definition of an open set?

Comment: Yes, the open sets are just the elements of the topology and the closed sets their complements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **by definition** the open sets are exactly the elements of the topology **T**$_\mathbb{S}$. The closed sets are **by definition** exactly the complements of the open sets *(keep in mind that a set can be open, closed, both, or neither!)*. So there's nothing to show, really. (It's trivially true that for every $A\in$ **T**$_\mathbb{S}$ and $a\in A$ there is some open $B\ni a$ with $B\subseteq A$ - namely, just take $B=A$.)

---

Things are a bit more interesting when we're not given the whole topology right up front. For $X$ a set an $\mathcal{T}$ a collection of subsets of $X$, the **topology on $X$ generated by $\mathcal{T}$** is the coarsest topology containing $\mathcal{T}$ (= making all subsets of $\mathcal{T}$ open); concretely, it's the set of finite intersections of arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ (this is a good exercise; incidentally, we use the convention that the intersection of zero things is $X$ and the union of zero things is $\emptyset$). If we're merely given a generating set for a topology, it may take some work to get a "concrete" characterization of when a set is open.

It's worth noting that every $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ generates a topology, although particular types of families of sets - **bases** and **subbases** - are especially convenient topology-generators.

Comment: “The closed sets are by definition exactly the complements of the open sets” — there are several (equivalent) definitions of closed sets, and this is one one of them. Of course it is always true that the closed sets are the complements of the open sets, but whether it is true *by definition* depends on which definition you use.

Answer (score 1):

A topology is a pair $(X, \tau)$ with $X$ some set and $\tau\subset P(X)$ satisfying some rules. The elements of $\tau$ are *defined* to be the open sets in $X$, and closed sets are simply sets whose complement in $X$ is open. Thus, the elements of $\mathbf{T}_\mathbb{S}$ are exactly the open sets and their complements (whose complements are the open sets themselves, thus closed), $\{\mathbb{S}, \{b, c, d\}, \{a, c, d\}, \dots, \emptyset\}$, are the closed sets.

Comment: Using this same example, how would I find cl$(\{a,b\})$? The definition I have is that it is the union of the set and its derived set. So I would have to check to see if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are limit points. But because $\{\alpha\}\in \mathbf{T}$ and it doesn't meet our subset in a point other than $\alpha$ it can't be a limit point right? Assuming the same logic would hold for $\beta$ too